# Prevent Android ICS downloading updates automatically

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, application-autoupdate

Can I prevent automatic update(system and app updates) downloads on **Android ICS** in order to reduce the bandwidth usage while using volume based internet data packages?

Comment: Hummm... volume based internet data packages as in using mobile data? Why not use Wifi?

Comment: Well, I want to update only when wifi connection is available. Wifi connection may not be available everywhere, so i have to use volume based data packages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable Automatic updates from Google Play Store app. Head over to Settings → Auto-update apps.

You can also set it to Update over Wi-Fi only, from the same settings page

Comment: But, this is not preventing system/security updates (such as Jelly Bean 4.2 system update).

Answer (score 3):

To prevent app updates over your data plan, go to the Google Play app > Settings > Auto-update apps > Auto-update apps over Wi-Fi only.

To prevent system updates over your data plan, go to your phone's Settings > Connections > Data usage > select Google Play Services from the list of apps > check "Restrict background data".

By doing both of these, you will still be able to get app and system updates over wifi (when connected) and you will save a lot on your volume based internet data packages.

Comment: @wbogacz That's not quite true. The stuff about Google Play Services is only in this answer. It's a good addition.

Comment: No one fully answered how to prevent "system AND app updates". This answers the question completely.

Answer (score 1):

There's two ways to deal with this:

- Try [Droidwall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.droidwall.free) to block outgoing connections on 3G data, in that way, if in the vicinity of the wifi network, Droidwall will allow data over Wifi.
- The other way is to go into Settings > More... Tap on that, Mobile Networks > uncheck Data enabled to prevent 3G data in and out.

Only ***caveat emptor*** with Droidwall, it requires rooted handset.

Comment: method 2 will prevent accessing internet from any apps (that are using low bandwidth, like messenger), right?

Comment: yes that's correct - cannot have it both ways :)

Comment: you can, actually.

Comment: my bad, completely forgot about that setting in the play store... :)